# Kotlin : TelephonyManager.getImei() Call requires permission which may be rejected by user

Tags: android, kotlin, telephonymanager

I'am developping an android app with Kotlin, i use the api 28.
I want to get the deviceId number.At the begining i use TelephonyManager.deviceId, after some research,i found that it's deprecated.
I found as solution, replace deviceId by getImei()
The following an excerpt from my code:

```
 val telephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        if (telephonyManager != null) {

            val androidID = Settings.Secure.getString(this.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
            if (androidID != null) {
                Utility().DEVICE_ID = androidID
                Utility().setDataBykeyValue(applicationContext, AppController.SHAIRD_PREF_DEVICE_ID, androidID)
            } else {
                val devId = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) telephonyManager.getImei()
                 else telephonyManager.getDeviceId()
                Utility().DEVICE_ID  = devId
                Utility().setDataBykeyValue(applicationContext, AppController.SHAIRD_PREF_DEVICE_ID, devId)
            }
            Utility().CARRIER = telephonyManager.simOperatorName

        }
```

Also i add this permission to my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

the "telephonyManager.getImei()" is underline with a red line, and the following msg appear :

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should
>   explicitly check to see if permission is available (with
>   checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential

I want to know what's the problem and how can i correct it

Comment: Check whether you have the permission or not before making the method call.

Comment: How can i check ?

Comment: you have to implement runtime permissions. It is not enough just to declare it in manifest

Comment: Check [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to know how to properly request a permission & treat the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Java:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);
   } else {
       // else for if they have already given permission
   }
}
```

You can check this tutorial also: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/

For Kotlin:

```
 val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)

 if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE), 1)
  }
```

You can check this tutorial also: https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Kotlin_-_Making_Runtime_Permission_Requests_in_Android

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String getImei(TelephonyManager tm) {
        String imei;
        try{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                imei = tm.getDeviceId(0);
            }else{
                imei = tm.getDeviceId();
            }
        }catch(SecurityException e){
            imei = "";
        }
        return imei;
    }
```